# Can't access BatchReadReceiptAsync using the FormRecognizerClientExtensions (C# Nuget library)

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, receipt, azure-form-recognizer

1. I have installed nuget Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.FormRecognizer --version 0.8.0-preview
2. I am trying to read receipts using the BatchReadReceiptAsync but its not available.
3. I have grabbed the code from github and integrated in my code manually. There is a problem in this code related to the operation id being the full URL and not the partial url.
4. Lastly the results of the form recognizer (receipts) are currently poor in Australia. It tends to detect "total gst" as the total instead of the receipt total

Answer (score 1):

Form Recognizer API is in preview and several versions have been released:

- 1.0, see [doc](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel)
- 2.0, see [doc](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm)

Prebuilt Receipts model has been released in January 2020 as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/whats-new?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#january-2020), so I guess the issue is that this package is too old.

There seems to be a total rebuild of the dotnet SDK currently in progress as you can see here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer

So currently, as this `Azure.AI.FormRecognizer` Nuget package is not published, you can't access the Receipt analysis operation directly using a package (as a workaround, you can still use the API directly).